# How do I install Heroku using CURL on mac? Error with tar file

Tags: curl, heroku

I am trying to install Heroku using the standalone installation method here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install.

After running the command "curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh" in the terminal and inputting  my login, I get an error that looks like this:

```
Installing CLI from https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-darwin-arm.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   359  100   359    0     0   1768      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1768
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a macOS machine handy, but it looks like [its `tar` doesn't support the `-J` parameter](https://ss64.com/osx/tar.html) that would normally filter the archive through `xz`. The install script you're using assumes that `tar` supports `-J` if `xz` is found on the system:

```sh
if [ $(command -v xz) ]; then
  URL=https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-$OS-$ARCH.tar.xz
  TAR_ARGS="xJ"
else
  URL=https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz
  TAR_ARGS="xz"
fi
```

You could modify the script to just use the code in the `else` clause, but the recommended way to install the Heroku CLI on macOS is to use Homebrew:

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

If that's not to your liking, feel free to simply download [the tarball](https://ss64.com/osx/tar.html) and extract it manually.